# Reportlab Muiltidoc pass args to canvasmaker

Tags: python-3.x, django, reportlab

I am trying to pass custom values via my canvasmaker. But i can't create an instance of Canvas or pass values to it.

This is my canvas Class.

```
class PracticeBookCanvas(canvas.Canvas):
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """Constructor"""
        # canvas.Canvas.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        canvas.Canvas.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.pages = []
     
    # def __init__(self, filename, subject_name, branch_name, *args, **kwargs):
    #     canvas.Canvas.__init__(self, filename, *args, **kwargs)
    #     self.pages = []
    #     self.subject_name = subject_name
    #     self.branch_name = branch_name
           
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def showPage(self):
        """
        On a page break, add information to the list
        """
        self.pages.append(dict(self.__dict__))
        self._startPage()
        
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def save(self):
        """
        Add the page number to each page (page x of y)
        """
        page_count = len(self.pages)
        
        for page in self.pages:
            self.__dict__.update(page)
            self.draw_page_number(page_count)
            self.draw_page_header()
            canvas.Canvas.showPage(self)
            
        canvas.Canvas.save(self)
        
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def draw_page_number(self, page_count):
        """
        Add the page number
        """
        page = "Page %s" % (self._pageNumber)
        self.setFont("Noto-Sans", 9)
        # self.drawRightString(195*mm, 272*mm, page)
        self.drawCentredString(195*mm, 0.4 * inch, page)
    
    def draw_page_header(self):
        self.setFont('Raleway', 14)
        self.drawString(self._pagesize[0] / 2, letter[1] - 0.5 * inch, "Practice Workbook")        
        # self.drawString(self._pagesize[0] / 2, letter[1] - 0.5 * inch, f"{self.subject} / {self.branch}")
```

This is my function which generates doc.

```
def genPracticeWorkbook(user, branch, level):
    logger.info(f"Generating Practice Workbook {user}")
    
    BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

    usr = User.objects.get(id=user)
    # user_downloads = UserDownloads.objects.all()
    user_downloads = UserDownloads(
        user=usr, status="in_progress", file_name=f"Practice Workbook_{level}"
    )
    
    pdf_buffer = BytesIO()

    user_downloads.save()
    
    assessment_grade_mapping = {
        100: 5,
        75: 4,
        50: 3,
        25: 2,
        10: 1,
    }
    
    doc = PracticeBookTemplate(pdf_buffer, pagesize=letter)
    story = []

    styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
    style = styles["Normal"]

    table_width = letter[0] * 0.85
    
    toc = TableOfContents()
    toc.levelStyles = [
        ParagraphStyle(fontName='Noto-Sans-Bold', fontSize=14, name='TOCHeading1',leftIndent=20, firstLineIndent=-20, spaceBefore=5, leading=16),
        ParagraphStyle(fontName='Noto-Sans', fontSize=12, name='TOCHeading2',leftIndent=40, firstLineIndent=-20, spaceBefore=0, leading=12),
    ]
    
    story.append(toc)
    story.append(PageBreak())
    
    subject_name = ''
    branch_name = ''

    levels = Level.objects.filter( level__startswith=level).all().order_by('level')
    print(levels)
    for sub in Subject.objects.all():
        #My code for loops which sets subject_name and branch_name and creates pdf content
```

I have tried creating instance of class and passing value but it doesn't work and it throws error as `PracticeBookCanvas` not callable.

```
filename = f"Practice Workbook_{subject_name}_{level}.pdf"
    my_canvas = PracticeBookCanvas(
        filename=filename,
        subject_name=subject_name,
        branch_name=branch_name
    )
    doc.multiBuild(story, canvasmaker=my_canvas)
```

I wish to pass subject_name as header on everypage which is not set until loop is run inside function.